# Strange behavior in while loop

Tags: java

I'm writing a function to take a turn in Blackjack.  It looks like this:

```
public void takeTurn(Deck deck) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    String response = "y";
    while (response.toLowerCase().equals("y")) {
    System.out.print("Would you like another card? (Y or N) ");
        response = reader.nextLine();
        if (response.toLowerCase().equals("y")) {
            hand.getCards().add(deck.getTopCard());
            System.out.println("Current hand: " + hand);
            if (hand.getValue() > 21) {
                System.out.println("You busted with " + hand.getValue());
                break;
            }
        }           
    } 
}
```

The weird thing is that when I enter "n", it doesn't draw another card but it *does* re-prompt me.  So then I threw in a printLine statement, as follows:

```
public void takeTurn(Deck deck) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    String response = "y";
    while (response.toLowerCase().equals("y")) {
        System.out.println("response is " + response);
        System.out.print("Would you like another card? (Y or N) ");
        response = reader.nextLine();
        if (response.toLowerCase().equals("y")) {
            hand.getCards().add(deck.getTopCard());
            System.out.println("Current hand: " + hand);
            if (hand.getValue() > 21) {
                System.out.println("You busted with " + hand.getValue());
                break;
            }
        }           
    } 
}
```

And here's a sample interaction:

```
response is y
Would you like another card? (Y or N) n
response is y
Would you like another card? (Y or N)
```

The first "response is y" makes sense.  The second I can't explain.

Any ideas?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue, the code works fine for me - how are you running it, from an IDE or via command line compiling and running? In the later case you might have an outdated version lying around

Comment: Try to create a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Where is that method called from? It seems it is called again and again. You can try to add a print at the end of `takeTurn` that says "Leaving takeTurn" and see for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    takeTurn(new Scanner(System.in)); // just an example how you share a single Scanner as a parameter when calling takeTurn function
}

public static void takeTurn(Scanner sc/*, Deck deck*/) { // static may be removed if you do not use the function within static main void
    if (isYResponse(sc, "Would you like another card? (Y or N) ")) {
        System.out.println("response is y");
        /*
        hand.getCards().add(deck.getTopCard());
        System.out.println("Current hand: " + hand);
        if (hand.getValue() > 21) {
            System.out.println("You busted with " + hand.getValue());
        }
        */
    } else {
        System.out.println("response is n");
    }
    takeTurn(sc/*, deck.next()*/); // be careful with this loop: define when it stops actually... when isGameOver(), for example?
}

private static boolean isYResponse(Scanner sc, String message) { // static may be removed if you do not use the function within static main void
    System.out.print(message);
    String response;
    if ((response = sc.nextLine()).isEmpty()) {
        response = sc.nextLine();
    }
    return ("y".compareToIgnoreCase(response) == 0)
            ? true
            : (("n".compareToIgnoreCase(response) == 0)
                ? false
                : isYResponse(sc, message));
}
```

---

P.S. I'm sorry: I don't know the structure of other classes, like Deck, for example. I just hope my answer can help you find the final concrete solution you need if you think that way.